# Autowired not working with event hub sample

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

I am trying to implement the eventhub example from microsoft to receive  event from event hubs 
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-receive-eph

I have created these classes in a spring boot application, and i am able to print out the messages.

I wanted to process these events, so I decided to create a service. 
The @Autowired is not able to load the service from the context. I dont know why;

```
@SpringBootApplication
    public class EventProcessorSample
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
    {
############



        host.registerEventProcessor(EventProcessor.class, options)
        .whenComplete((unused, e) ->
        {


#######
        System.out.println("End of sample");
    }
```

The problem is here : The service is NULL
I have tried @Component or @Service to this class.. but the service is not populated.

```
public static class EventProcessor implements IEventProcessor
{
    private int checkpointBatchingCount = 0;
@Autowired
ProcessingService processingservice;

    // onEvents is called when events are received on this partition of the Event Hub. 
    @Override
    public void onEvents(PartitionContext context, Iterable<EventData> events) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("SAMPLE: Partition " + context.getPartitionId() + " got event batch");
        int eventCount = 0;
        for (EventData data : events)
        {
            try
            {
                processingservice.process(new String(data.getBytes(), "UTF8"));

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Processing failed for an event: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("SAMPLE: Partition " + context.getPartitionId() + " batch size was " + eventCount + " for host " + context.getOwner());
    }
}
```

Service :

```
@Service
public class ProcessingService {

public void process(String myMessage){
//Call Repository
}

}
```

Is it because the registerHostProcessor is using a class type as parameter?
How can I load the service to process and call the repository afterwards?

Thanks.

Package is simple springboot application

```
src/main/java
 |
 +-- EventProcessorSample
 |    
 +-- service
 |  |  
 |  +-- ProcessingService
 |    
 +-- processor
 |  |  
 |  +-- EventProcessor
 |    
 +-- repository
 |  |  
 +  |-- MyRepository
```

Comment: can you post you packaging structure? and also have used `new` keyword in any class to create object?

Comment: Package is simple springboot application

    src/main/java
     |
     +-- EventProcessorSample
     |    
     +-- service
     |  |  
     |  +-- ProcessingService
     |    
     +-- processor
     |  |  
     |  +-- EventProcessor
     |    
     +-- repository
     |  |  
     +  |-- MyRepository

Comment: its really hard, can you post an image or update in code?

Comment: I suck at markdown . Updated in the question  :)

Comment: does this code compile? how can you declare outer class as static `public static class EventProcessor implements IEventProcessor`?

Comment: You are right, I removed the static from the code to put it in another file/class. No change from the microsoft code though..    

  I feel that this bit of code of creating a  **new** might be the cause
(Piece of code from the main class..see the link in question)...    

   EventProcessorHost host = new EventProcessorHost(
             EventProcessorHost.createHostName(hostNamePrefix),
             eventHubName,
             consumerGroupName,
             eventHubConnectionString.toString(),
             storageConnectionString,
             storageContainerName);

Comment: @testeurFou I am also struck with the same issue. Have you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the registration code from:

```
 host.registerEventProcessor(EventProcessor.class, options)
```

to

```
@Autowired
    private EventProcessorFactory eventProcessorFactory;
...
    host.registerEventProcessorFactory(eventProcessorFactory)
```

Where

```
@Component
public class EventProcessorFactory implements IEventProcessorFactory<EventProcessor> {

    @Autowired
    ProcessingService processingservice;

    @Override
    public EventProcessor createEventProcessor(PartitionContext context) throws Exception {
        return new EventProcessor(processingservice);
    }

}
```

EventProcessorFactory is a component where Spring manages the life cycle. You can inject whatever you want to EventProcessorFactory, and then you can pass to the EventProcessor when you create it inside the factory method.
In this way you start to have control on the EventProcessor instances creation.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your `EventProcessor` class should also be a Spring bean - add `@Component` and make sure Spring's component scanning mechanism can find the annotated class...

```
@Component
public class EventProcessor implements IEventProcessor
{
    private int checkpointBatchingCount = 0;
    private ProcessingService processingservice;

    // constructor injection of mandatory dependencies
    public EventProcessor(ProcessingService processingService) {
        this.processingService = processingService;
    }

    // onEvents is called when events are received on this partition of the Event Hub. 
    @Override
    public void onEvents(PartitionContext context, Iterable<EventData> events) throws Exception
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that, and not working. I have adde also a component scan at pakage level also..not working

Comment: I added cofigurable with the package name below the @springbootapplication.

Comment: alright, just make sure you additionally annotate your main class with `@ComponentScan("your.package.to.be.scanned")`

as mentioned here: http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-and-component-scan

besides that, I believe my EventProcessor implementation should work...